# MongDB: Query to extract dynamic key, value pair from nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

The below-given is my data structure, I have a requirement to extract "publishers" dynamic keys and compare ($lookup) with another collection for matching records, sum the % values.

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5eff1e9a9bb60729d3278140"),
    "tracks" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5efd9548327f5509b009b5a9"),
            "artist" : ["abc"],
            "genre" : "Pop",
            "publishers" : {
                "a" : "30.00%",
                "b" : "30.00%",
                "c" : "30.00%",
                "d" : "10.00%"
            },
            "__v" : 0
        }
```

1. Is the data structure valid?
2. I'm trying to convert this into $ObjectToArray but not able to convert the nested documents, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation pipeline. It will convert your **dynamic keys** in publishers array to an object of the following form, after that you can apply your `$lookup` stage easily.

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5eff1e9a9bb60729d3278140"),
    "percentage": 30,
    "publisher": "b"
  }
```

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$tracks"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      publisher: {
        $objectToArray: "$tracks.publishers"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$publisher"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      publisher: "$publisher.k",
      percentage: {
        $convert: {
          input: {
            $trim: {
              input: "$publisher.v",
              chars: "%"
            }
          },
          to: "double"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoDB Playground Ex. - 1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/L8zkGnZVvRP)

---

### Updated example

[MongoDB Playground Ex. - 2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5qIMb8OvZra)

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for your response, i'm able to get the expected results.Can i check with you one more thing, please find my query here "https://mongoplayground.net/p/bnGSqbl92bZ" and suggest me, is this a recommended approach ?

Comment: I have added another example after seeing your DB structure above. You can modify this query to your required needs.

Comment: Thanks for providing the sample, looks like you had changed the given data structure, it works on your data structure, not  in mine. Please find the actual structure and would like to get the result set as tracks details with total contribution (sum of each matching publisher percentage) and indicator flag true/false (true = 100%, False <>  100%).

Complete Data Structure:"https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z-qNt6IWhg7"

Comment: this totally deviates from the actual question itself, you need to post another question and explain what you want to achieve

Comment: The actual issue has been posted and the given solution works with the different data structures than the one provided, so I'm trying to get the solution make it work with four individual collections than single nested collection, please advise.

Comment: where have you posted the question ?

Comment: Here is same old link, https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z-qNt6IWhg7

Comment: first, you have converted your data from  BSON to JSON 
`"_id": {
    "$oid": "5ef22a28cb1ee73378d9b91e"
  }`, second, see your original question it is very much different from what you want to achieve, so what I am suggesting is make another question on StackOverflow regarding the same with BSON data not converted BSON to JSON data

Comment: Please find the question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62776938/calculate-sum-using-dynamic-key-value-pair-from-nested-documents-with-other-col